# How to make the image appear with an animation effect from right to left

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.
Have imported  two images:

```
import  Benji_image from '../benji.png';
import  Casper_image  from '../image_3.png';
```

i have created a constructor and super(), both containing property props.
Therefore i have created a state that will carry those image that i have imported in my component.
And i have bind a method that i created. This method will update the state with those images

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                   name_1_profile_image0: React.createElement("img", {
                   src: Casper_image,
                   alt: "Casper",
                   id: "current_img"
                }),
                  name_2_profile_image: React.createElement("img", {
                  src: Benji_image,
                  alt: "Casper",
                  id: "next_img"
        }),
    }
    this.imageHandler = this.imageHandler.bind(this);
}
```

This is the method i have created.

```
imageHandler(){
    this.setState({
        name_1_profile_image: !this.state.name_1_profile_image,
        name: !this.state.name,
        profile_info: !this.state.profile_info,
        quote: !this.state.quote
    })
}
```

And this is the render code before the return

```
render(){
    var image = this.state.name_1_profile_image ? this.state.name_2_profile_image : this.state.name_1_profile_image0;
    }
```

And the return:

```
 <div className="profile_image">
   <picture>
     {image}
  </picture>
```

And this is the result:
[This](https://media.giphy.com/media/UrD8Q4NyvIEy1sisnW/giphy.gif)
when you click on where it says "View Casper Lee -->"
The previous image will be replaced or changed to the new one, you can clearly see the information changing too.

THIS IS THE QUESTION FOR MY PROBLEM!
What I want is that before the second image (Benji) appear, I want to give it a`transition of 1s`
and slide from right to left. I want that effect to happen. I just do not want the image to just appear like that. I want it to show up from the right side to its position where it must be.
I have no idea on how i can implement this with css, i tried :active or :focus but was not working or i did it wrong maybe. if it is possible in Javascript but within react then that is still good for me.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/1/) is a similar thing I want for my second image (Benji).

Please help me out.
Thanks alot in advance.

This is just a full code of my component

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import  Benji_image from '../benji.png';
import  Casper_image  from '../image_3.png';

class RoomList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: false,
            name_1_profile_image: false,
            profile_info: false,
            quote: false,
            profile_name_1: 'Casper Lee',
            profile_name_2: 'Benji Schaffer',
            profile_quote_name_1: 'An interesting Casper quote goes here',
            profile_quote_name_2: 'An interesting Benji quote goes here',
            name_1_story_paragraph: React.createElement("div", {
                class: "para-wrap"
              }, React.createElement("p", {
                className: "story_paragraph"
              }, "In 2018, he co-founded Margravine Management with Joe Sugg. IMG invested and is a strategic partner to the company. He continued to work alongside The Queen\u2019s Young Leaders and was invited to meet the Queen for a second year at Buckingham Palace."), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", {
                className: "story_paragraph"
              }, "In 2019, he co-founded Creative Investment Club which is a syndicate of top creators from around the world investing together in companies at their Pre-Seed, Seed, Series A, and Series B stages. Notable investments include Dash Water and Faceit."), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", {
                class: "story_paragraph"
              }, "In 2019, he co-founded Creative Investment Club which is a syndicate of top creators from around the world investing together in companies at their Pre-Seed, Seed, Series A, and Series B stages. Notable investments include Dash Water and Faceit.'")),

            name_2_story_paragraph: React.createElement("div", {
                class: "para-wrap"
              }, React.createElement("p", {
                className: "story_paragraph"
              }, "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using."), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", {
                className: "story_paragraph"
              }, "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage."), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", {
                class: "story_paragraph"
              }, "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia.")),
            name_2_story_paragraph_1: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using',
            name_2_story_paragraph_2: 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage',
            name_2_story_paragraph_3: 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia',
            name_1_profile_image0: React.createElement("img", {
                src: Casper_image,
                alt: "Casper",
                id: "current_img"
            }),
            name_2_profile_image: React.createElement("img", {
                src: Benji_image,
                alt: "Casper",
                id: "next_img"
            }),
        }
        this.imageHandler = this.imageHandler.bind(this);
    }


    imageHandler(){
        this.setState({
            name_1_profile_image: !this.state.name_1_profile_image,
            name: !this.state.name,
            profile_info: !this.state.profile_info,
            quote: !this.state.quote
        })
    }






    render(){
        var image = this.state.name_1_profile_image ? this.state.name_2_profile_image : this.state.name_1_profile_image0;
        var profileName = this.state.name ? this.state.profile_name_2 : this.state.profile_name_1;
        var profileInfo = this.state.profile_info ? this.state.name_2_story_paragraph : this.state.name_1_story_paragraph;
        var quote = this.state.quote ? this.state.profile_quote_name_2 : this.state.profile_quote_name_1;

        return(
            <div className="room-list">
                <header>
                    <h2 className="mg-bottom">Meet The People Behind</h2>
                    <h2 className="mg-top">Proper Living</h2>
                </header>
                <div className="profile">
                    <div className="profile_image">
                        <picture>
                            {image}
                        </picture> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="profile_info">
                        <div className="profile_name">
                            <h5>
                            {profileName}
                            <hr />
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div className="profile_quote">
                            <q>{quote}</q>
                        </div>
                        <div className="profile_storyline">
                            {profileInfo}
                            <div className="button" onClick={this.imageHandler}>
                                <h6>View Caspar Lee -></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RoomList;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [toRight, setToRight] = useState(false)
  const imageRef = () => {
    if(!toRight) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setToRight(true)
      })
    }
  }

  const toggle = () => setToRight(prev => !prev)
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={toggle}>
      <img alt="googlePhoto" ref={imageRef} className={toRight ? "toRight" : "toLeft"} src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/screen-shot-2015-10-08-at-4-20-16-pm.png?w=730&crop=1"/>
    </div>
  );
}


//styles.css

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.toRight {
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 1s
}

.toLeft {
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 1s
}
```

here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ride-lg1ej?file=/src/styles.css:0-160)

Comment: Hi, Ehsan.  I have tried your solution, however, there is no effect. There is just nothing and the image is not getting any effect. I have seen the react transition group but i'm not sure how to use it. in this case.

Comment: your demo is showing only a picture of google. It is still not working

Comment: it's the solution but there may be some bug so feel free to fix it